# Searching and replacing between files

Tags: regex, shell, grep, text-processing

There are two files: `file1` and `file2`

The contents at the end of `file1`:

```
support:
 -hjk
 -jhj

name:
 akklk
 jhlkjj
 pklkkl
```

In `file2` these contents are present somewhere.

In file2:

```
support:
 kdfdgfg
 dfgfg
 gfkll;';'

#jdddddfbgbgbbbbbbbbbb

fklfdfklkl;

name:
 -efffffffff
 -ccccc
 -effff

#bbknlvkmlkjml
```

I need to copy the lines starting from `support:`, until it finds a line beginning with `#` and also copy lines starting from `name:` until it finds a line beginning with `#` in `file2` and append it at the end of `file1`.
How to do it with `grep`?

Comment: better show more relevant input to make it more clear. Currently it is quite fuzzy

Comment: `sed` should be able to do this with a range.

Answer (score 0):

That `grep` pattern extracts the part from `file2` and appends it to `file1`:

```
grep -Pzo '^(support:|name:)(((?!^#).)*\n)*' file2 >>file1
```

**Explanation** of the regex:

- `-P`: use perl regular expressions
- `-z`: macthe linebreaks with `\n`
- `-o`: only print matched lines
- `^(support:|name:)`: searches for lines starting with `support:` or `name:`
- `(((?!^#).)*\n)*`: Then followed by a pattern that does not match a line that starts with `#`, it's a negative [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?!^#)`. This is followed by any character (`.`), and all that can appear zero or multiple times (`*`), again followed by a newline (`\n`). And again: all that can appear zero or multiple times (the last `*`).
- `>>file1`: The `>>` operator appends the standard output to `file1`

Answer (score 0):

grep is the wrong tool, you should be using awk. grep is for doing `g/re/p`, that's all (there is a big clue in its name!).

```
$ awk '/(support|name):/{f=1} f; /^#/{f=0}' file2
support:
 kdfdgfg
 dfgfg
 gfkll;';'

#jdddddfbgbgbbbbbbbbbb
name:
 -efffffffff
 -ccccc
 -effff

#bbknlvkmlkjml
```

or if you don't want the terminating line included in the output:

```
$ awk '/(support|name):/{f=1} /^#/{f=0} f' file2
support:
 kdfdgfg
 dfgfg
 gfkll;';'

name:
 -efffffffff
 -ccccc
 -effff
```